# The program does not work. The code needs to extract files from zip archive and than delete zip archive

Tags: powershell

The program does not work.

The code needs to extract files from zip archive and than delete zip archive. The program does not extract the file from the archive.

```
# Config 
$Username = "xxx@xxxx.ru" 
$Password = "xxxxxx" 
$LocalFile = "C:\Prices\TechnoMarin\price.zip" 
$RemoteFile = "ftp://00.00.00.00/price.zip" 


    # Create a FTPWebRequest 
    $FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($RemoteFile) 
    $FTPRequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username,$Password) 
    $FTPRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DownloadFile 
    $FTPRequest.UseBinary = $true 
    $FTPRequest.KeepAlive = $false 
    # Send the ftp request 
    $FTPResponse = $FTPRequest.GetResponse() 
    # Get a download stream from the server response 
    $ResponseStream = $FTPResponse.GetResponseStream() 
    # Create the target file on the local system and the download buffer 
    $LocalFileFile = New-Object IO.FileStream ($LocalFile,[IO.FileMode]::Create) 
    [byte[]]$ReadBuffer = New-Object byte[] 1024 
    # Loop through the download 
    do { 
    $ReadLength = $ResponseStream.Read($ReadBuffer,0,1024) 
    $LocalFileFile.Write($ReadBuffer,0,$ReadLength) 
    } 
    while ($ReadLength -ne 0)

    #Wait-Event -Timeout 50

    Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"

    $ArchiveFileName = "C:\Prices\TechnoMarin\price.zip"

    $ExtractPath = "C:\Prices\TechnoMarin\"

    [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($ArchiveFileName, $ExtractPath)
```

I get this error:

> C: \ prices \ TechnoMarin> powershell.exe -noexit C: \ prices \ TechnoMarin \ price.ps1
>
> Exception when calling "ExtractToDirectory" with "2" arguments: "The process cannot access the file" C: \ Prices \ TechnoMarin \ price.zip "because this file is being used by another process.
>
> C: \ prices \ TechnoMarin \ price.ps1: 35 sign: 1
>   + [IO.Compression.ZipFile] :: ExtractToDirectory ($ ArchiveFileName, $ Extra ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId: IOException

Comment: Use [Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-6) for deleting.

Answer (score 0):

The FileStream is opened and written into, but never released. Thus the opening object holds a write lock for the file, and extraction part cannot access the file.

Try and include a `.Close()` after the file's been downloaded. Like so,

```
do { 
  $ReadLength = $ResponseStream.Read($ReadBuffer,0,1024) 
  $LocalFileFile.Write($ReadBuffer,0,$ReadLength) 
}  while ($ReadLength -ne 0)
# All data has been written, close the file.
$LocalFileFile.Close()

Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"
...
```